# Fetch all images in a container and display it as smaller thumbnails in another container

Tags: javascript, html, image, gallery

I have a static webpage with over 50-100 images and I want to create a separate container to show each image as a thumbnail. When clicking on the image, it should bring you to the image. I'm having issues when you click on the image and it should bring you to that image on the page.

```
// loop through img elements
$('.img-class').each(function(){

    // create new image object
    image = new Image();

    // assign img src attribute value to object src property
    image.src = $(this).attr('src');

    var xx = document.getElementById('gallery');
    xx.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<img src="'+ image.src +'"/>');

});
```

Sample of the HTML:

```
<div id='mydata'>
  <img src='x.jpg'/>
  <img src='1.jpg'/>
  <img src='2.jpg'/>
  <img src='3.jpg'/>
</div>

<div id='gallery'>
  <a href="goto-x-image"><img src='x.jpg' width='50' height='50'/></a>
  <a href="goto-1-image"><img src='1.jpg' width='50' height='50'/></a>
  <a href="goto-2-image"><img src='2.jpg' width='50' height='50'/></a>
  <a href="goto-3-image"><img src='3.jpg' width='50' height='50'/></a>
</div>
```

The gallery is generated when the page loads.

Comment: `I'm having issues when you click on the image` - can you describe the issue? How can we test this - can you show the HTML or some of?

Comment: I basically have a static HTML page which is just an exported chatroom data. In this page, there are 50-100 of image tags that I want to process and just show up in a separate container in a small thumbnail. When the user clicks on these thumbnails, it should bring you to the section of the chat that references this image.

Comment: You'll need to provide a sample of the HTML - as it is this is quite hard to underdstand. The above piece of javascript adds to the DOM yet you say that you wish the user to be taken to a particular part of the page.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius basic sample of the html. im working with. THX!